# How to trigger an unwind segue with the "return" key on the iPhone keyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, segue

I've learned that you can control-drag from a button to the exit button in the storyboard to trigger an unwind segue.  However, I would like an unwind segue to be triggered when the user presses the return key in the pop-up keyboard after editing a text box.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drag from the controller icon (at the bottom of the scene) to the exit icon instead of from a button. Then, the segue will only be performed when you call it in code. Call performSegueWithIdentifier in the textFieldShouldReturn: delegate method. Of course, don't forget to give the segue an identifier.